# Malloc reserva memoria por detrás del puntero

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Solicité a malloc tres espacios de memoria y me reservó un bloque de memoria atrás del puntero, lo cual me parece super raro y no entiendo el porque del comportamiento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien quiere revisar el código es este (ejemplo mínimo verifica ble)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RESERVE_MEMORY_FAIL 500;

int countDigits(int num, int * numSize){
    do{
        (* numSize)++;
        num /= 10;
    } while(num != 0);
    return 0;
}


int integerToString(int num, char ** strNum, int* strNumSize){
    *strNumSize = 0;
    countDigits(num, strNumSize);
    free(*strNum); *strNum = 0x0;
    *strNum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(*strNumSize));
    if(*strNum == 0x0) return RESERVE_MEMORY_FAIL;
    for(int i = (*strNumSize-1); i > -1; i--){
            **(strNum+i) = num%10 + '0';
            num /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num = 111;
    int numStrSize = 0;
    char * numStr = 0x0;

    int err = integerToString(num, &numStr, &numStrSize);
    if(err > 0) return err;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código tiene un pequeño fallo. Cuando reservas espacio para una cadena debes reservar 1 byte más para el terminador, y me parece que tampoco estás añadiendo ese terminador en tu función.

Aparte de esto, yendo a tu pregunta, parece que te has hecho un pequeño lío entre `strNum` y `*strNum`.

En tu función `strNum` es un puntero a la variable pasada por referencia desde `main()`, es decir, apunta a la variable `numStr` de `main()`. Esa variable es de tipo puntero a char.

Dentro de tu función asignas a `*strNum` lo que `malloc()` te devuelve. Eso es lo correcto. Por tanto `*strNum` apunta al bloque reservado con `malloc()`, pero `strNum` no. `strNum` apunta al puntero que apunta a ese bloque.

Cuando en el depurador haces `strNum-1`, debido a la aritmética de punteros, y que el tipo de `strNum` es "puntero a puntero", no estás restando 1 byte, sino `sizeof(char *)`, es decir, el tamaño de un puntero. Este tamaño depende de la arquitectura y será de 4 bytes en arquitecturas de 32 bits o de 8 en las de 64 bits.

Sea como sea, `strNum-1` apunta a otro "hipotético puntero" que estaría por detrás del puntero al que apunta `strNum`. Puesto que `strNum` apuntaba a la variable `numStr` de `main()`, `strNum-1` apuntará a otra variable local de `main()` (posiblemente a `numStrSize` o a `num`, aunque esto depende del tamaño del entero en tu sistema).

Al usar `**(strNum-1)`, primero se desreferencia `(strNum-1)`, es decir, se accede a `*(strNum-1)`. Si suponemos que `(strNum-1)` apuntaba a la variable `num` de `main()`, resultará que `*(strNum-1)` valdría 111. El segundo asterisco desreferenciaría ese valor tratándolo como un puntero a char. Ya que la dirección 111 está probablemente fuera del espacio de direcciones de tu proceso, será inaccesible.

En realidad, el resultado es imprevisible, pues depende de cómo se ordenen en memoria las variables locales y sus valores.

Probablemente lo que pretendías hacer era `*(*strNum -1)`, lo cual sí accedería 1 byte por detrás de la dirección retornada por malloc().

En todo caso, no te esperes que eso te vaya a denegar un acceso. `malloc()` apunta a una parte del *heap* de tu proceso, y es probable que la dirección anterior al bloque reservado pertenezca también a tu proceso, por lo que perfectamente podrías leer o escribir en ella (eso sí, con resultados imprevisibles, pues seguramente sea ahí donde `malloc()` guarde metainformación referente a ese bloque).

A donde sí que puedes acceder sin problemas, si has reservado 3 bytes, es a `*(*strNum)`, `*(*strNum+1)`  y `*(*strNum+2)`.

Comment: Eres amor, gracias UwU.
Me queda la duda del terminador, nunca escuche de el en mis clases, ¿Que debo poner en el espacio extra?

Comment: @Zush18 El terminador es un byte de valor 0. Puedes asignarlo directamente con el entero `0`, o con el carácter `'\0'` (que se codifica como el entero 0). Ese carácter ha de ir después de la última letra de la cadena. Todas las funciones C de manejo de cadenas esperan que esté terminada de ese modo. Sin él funciones como `strlen()` no funcionarán correctamente (seguirán contando letras más allá del final hasta que casualmente encuentren ese 0). Ni siquiera `printf("%s", cadena)` funcionará si `cadena` no tiene ese terminador.